# Why my matrix does not work properly java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, intellij-idea, multidimensional-array

Below is my matrix code, I want to fill the gaps with unique numbers. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work. I tried going step by step in it but I can't seem to figure where I have made a mistake. So, the thing is, I have a given 9 x 9 matrix with some numbers in it, and I want to complete the rest of it with unique numbers so that every line and column there is all numbers from 1 to 9 but different on each column / row.
Please help me, thank you!

```
package com.javagement;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] matriceBuni = new int[9][9];

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                matriceBuni[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        matriceBuni[0][0] = 8;
        matriceBuni[0][4] = 6;
        matriceBuni[0][8] = 4;
        matriceBuni[1][2] = 7;
        matriceBuni[1][4] = 3;
        matriceBuni[1][8] = 5;
        matriceBuni[2][0] = 3;
        matriceBuni[2][1] = 9;
        matriceBuni[2][5] = 5;
        matriceBuni[2][7] = 8;
        matriceBuni[3][2] = 8;
        matriceBuni[3][3] = 6;
        matriceBuni[3][6] = 7;
        matriceBuni[3][7] = 5;
        matriceBuni[4][2] = 5;
        matriceBuni[4][3] = 8;
        matriceBuni[4][7] = 9;
        matriceBuni[5][1] = 6;
        matriceBuni[5][2] = 3;
        matriceBuni[5][5] = 7;
        matriceBuni[5][6] = 4;
        matriceBuni[6][0] = 7;
        matriceBuni[6][1] = 3;
        matriceBuni[6][3] = 2;
        matriceBuni[6][5] = 9;
        matriceBuni[7][0] = 1;
        matriceBuni[7][1] = 8;
        matriceBuni[7][7] = 5;
        matriceBuni[7][8] = 9;
        matriceBuni[8][4] = 8;
        matriceBuni[8][5] = 1;
        matriceBuni[8][6] = 2;

        for(int m = 0; m < 9; m++) {
            for(int n = 0; n < 9; n++) {
                System.out.print(matriceBuni[m][n] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("*****************************************");



        for(int r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
                if(matriceBuni[r][c] == 0) {
                    boolean isUnique = false;
                    while(!isUnique) {
                        int uniqueNumber = getRandomNumberInRange(1,9);
                        int countUnique = 0;
                        for(int a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
                            if (matriceBuni[r][a] == uniqueNumber) {
                                countUnique++;
                            }
                        }
                         for(int b = 0; b < 9; b++) {
                             if (matriceBuni[b][c] == uniqueNumber) {
                                 countUnique++;
                             }
                         }
                        if (countUnique == 0) {
                            isUnique = true;
                            matriceBuni[r][c] = uniqueNumber;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        for(int m = 0; m < 9; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < 9; n++) {
                System.out.print(matriceBuni[m][n] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    private static int getRandomNumberInRange(int min, int max) {

        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-sudoku - Also, [When you dishonor your family and have to commit Sudoku](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/393luw/when_you_dishonor_your_family_and_have_to_commit/).

Comment: So you aren't getting a correctly filled matrix finally, right?

Comment: Thank you @ElliottFrisch but where can I get the final code? It's only for personal use anyway. And mettleap actually I don't get anything, the code keeps running on and on.

Comment: Click the first link. Scroll down to section "3.2. Solution"

Comment: Thank you I got it! Have a great evening!